# Javascript screen width get from php

Tags: javascript, php

i tried to do like this. i think its worthless

here my code..

```
<?php
$screen = '<script type="text/javascript">document.write(screen.width);</script>';
$echo $screen;
?>
```

this javascript code is work without php code..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(screen.width);
</script>
```

but i want to get only width from variable

i tried to like this get screen size from php.. but its not work.. someone can help me for do this one.. i want to variable for screen width.. if have another good method plz give me answer for this one.. thanks.

Comment: PHP is already _done_ with everything _before_ your JS code gets executed … If you lack even that basic kind of knowledge, you should first go read up on how these techniques work.

Comment: if u can plzz give me code to do this

Comment: I guess you could redirect to `page.php?screenWidth=***`, if the variable isn't set.

Comment: I think you first have to learn how JavaScript and PHP interrelate and how the client server model works. http://demosthenes.info/blog/137/The-Client-Server-Model

Comment: without redirect cant get screen width?

Comment: i dnt know about this code.. if i knw i dnt want help from u

Comment: Javascript runs on the client. PHP runs on the server. Until you understand the difference and what it means, I suggest you stop banging on this code.

Comment: 1) don't use `document.write`. 2) write your javascript in their own .js files and `<script src="thatfile.js"></script>` include them on the page you generate. There is nothing PHP can do server side that is relevant to the client-side browser properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in one of the comment, you need to differentiate client and server.

Though to make things simple, if you want to get screen width on server side, you can do the following :

**Index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_GET['width']) && !isset($_SESSION['screen.width'])){
?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
location.replace('http://example.com/?width='+screen.width);
</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
<?php
die();
}

if(isset($_GET['width'])){
    $_SESSION['screen.width'] = (int) $_GET['width'];
}

echo "screen width : ".$_SESSION['screen.width'];

?>
```